# Redirection depending of which checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys :) I have a little form that is giving me troubles

This is my code

```
<div class="unit">
<label class="input select">
<select name="position">
<option value="none" selected disabled="">Choose desired position</option>
<option value="tech lead">Tech Lead</option>
<option value="product manager">Product Manager</option>
<option value="senior developer">Senior Developer</option>
<option value="system administrator">System Administrator</option>
</select>
<i></i>
</label>
</div>
```

Now I want my Java to (after submission of form) redirect to links depending on which option was selected, is that even possible?

I use this to redirect and it works fine

```
$(location).attr('href, 'http://example.org')
```

thanks for your attentiom

Comment: do you want to do it with `Java` and `Servlets` for example, or with pure `Javascript`

Comment: pure javascript thanks for replying @KevinEsche

Comment: you want to do it in pure `js`. so there is need of `java` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to another url based on select option

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if(valueSelected === "tech lead")
    window.location = "http://www.yoururl1.com";
    else if(valueSelected === "product manager")
    window.location = "http://www.yoururl2.com";
    .........
});
```

Comment: Yes but i want different redirection for each option chosen @satya